# Unable to start a cron task as root

Tags: bash, scripts, cron

I use a program to check raid status. The command is `megaclisas-status`.

Here is the issue :

Has user `/usr/sbin/megaclisas-status` return : `This script requires Administrator privs` => OK

Has root `/usr/sbin/megaclisas-status` return : `-- Controller information -- ....` => OK

In root crontab `0 */12 * * * bash /root/scripts/script.sh > /root/log/script.log 2>&1` return : `This script requires Administrator privs` => WHY ???

Some one have an idea why I can't use this command in root crontab ?

---

Here is the content of the script.sh :

`raid=$(/usr/sbin/megaclisas-status)
/usr/bin/zabbix_sender -c /etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.conf -k system.raid.disk.status -o "$raid"`

---

Here is the rights of the scripts :
`-rwx------ 1 root root  131 févr. 11 14:11 scriptsh`

Answer (score 0):

The issue was not come from cron but programe itself.

It was written in python and `os.getenv("USER")` return none in cron, `os.getenv("LOGNAME")` fix the issue.